# Javascript Array: Change elements from string to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am using the ParamQuery JavaScript library ([ParamQuery Website](http://paramquery.com/grid)) to build a JavaScript grid.

With JQuery I make a request to my service using Ajax which retunrs JSON data. I then loop through my JSON data and assign it to an array. My problem is the elements are strings but I think they need to be an array of objects.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var DataArray = [];

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://wks52025:82/WcfDataService.svc/GetNotes()?$format=json",
            type: "get",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data.d, function (i, item) {
                    DataArray[i] = "[" + item.NotesTitle.trim() + "," + item.NotesText.trim() + "]";
                })

                for (var i = 0; i < DataArray.length; i++) {
                    //alert(DataArray[i]);
                    //Do something
                }

                // GRID LOGIC HERE
                var obj = { width: 800, height: 400, title: "Notes" };
                obj.colModel = [
                    { title: "NotesTitle", width: 500, dataType: "string" },
                    { title: "NotesText", width: 500, dataType: "string" } 
                ];
                obj.dataModel = { data: DataArray }; // Data Array goes here
                $("#grid_array").pqGrid(obj);
            }
        });    
    });
</script>
```

I have attached screenshots of my Watch tab in VS and a screenshot of how the grid renders after debug.

[image: Visual studio watch]

[image: My Grid]

[This is the example code](http://paramquery.com/demos)

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: If the screenshot is too small I can resize it. It looked bigger on paint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is only about turning this to array of objects take a look at this line:

```
$.each(data.d, function (i, item) {
  DataArray[i] = { NotesTitle: item.NotesTitle.trim(), NotesText:item.NotesText.trim() };
})
```

**Update**
Had a look a the example, you need an Array of arrays

```
$.each(data.d, function (i, item) {
  DataArray[i] = [  item.NotesTitle.trim(), item.NotesText.trim() ];
})
```

Comment: For this question it is. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Thanks that worked. I guess my use of brackets was incorrect for what I was trying to do.